# Animated ring graph on mousedown

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, canvas

I am working with a jquery library called circliful:

https://github.com/pguso/jquery-plugin-circliful

I am using it to create a "tactile loading" effect.

In this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4mftq2eq/1/ you can see how it currently functions. However, I am attempting to make the animation take place on `mousedown`, and then to reverse it on `mouseup`.

I've changed the animate function in the library just a little bit. (line 213, 242-256)

```
function animate(current, is_backward) {

     // original code here

     if(is_backward == true) {
         curPerc = 100;
     }

     if (curPerc < 100) {
         curPerc += 1;
         requestAnimationFrame(function () {
             animate(Math.min(curPerc, 100) / 100);
         }, obj);
     } else {
         curPerc -= 1;
            requestAnimationFrame(function () {
               animate(Math.min(0));
            }, obj);
     }
```

My attempt thus far has proven fruitless. (lines 267-274)

```
$('*').on('mousedown', function() {
     animate(curPerc / 100, false);
});
$('*').on('mouseup', function() {
     animate(curPerc / 100, true);
});
```

**I am only using the astrick selector for development purposes.**

broken fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4mftq2eq/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to write another call to `requestAnimationFrame()` in case that `is_backward` is true.
By wrapping them into variables, you can call the [`cancelAnimationFrame()`](http://jsfiddle.net/4mftq2eq/3/) method.

```
var forward, backward;

function animate(current, is_backward) {
     [...]
            if(is_backward) {
                cancelAnimationFrame(forward);
             if (curPerc > 0) {
                curPerc -= 1;
                backward= requestAnimationFrame(function () {
                    animate(Math.max(curPerc / 100, 0), true);
                }, obj);
            } else {

                curPerc =0;
                //here name your animationFrame
                backward= requestAnimationFrame(function () {
                    animate(0, true);
                }, obj);
            }
            }
           else{
                cancelAnimationFrame(backward);
            if (curPerc < 100) {
                curPerc += 1;
               //here name your animationFrame
               forward= requestAnimationFrame(function () {
                    animate(Math.min(curPerc, 100) / 100);
                }, obj);
            } else {
                curPerc =100;
                forward= requestAnimationFrame(function () {
                    animate(Math.min(0));
                }, obj);
            }
           }
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mftq2eq/3/)**